# Get current state of graph after elements are added dynamically

Tags: cytoscape.js

I am using Cytoscape.js and the [context menus extension](https://github.com/iVis-at-Bilkent/cytoscape.js-context-menus) within a React app through [react-cytoscape.js](https://github.com/plotly/react-cytoscapejs). Right now, I can dynamically add nodes through an onClickFunction as a menu item. I would like to get the current state of the graph - that is, all the nodes that have been added as well as the ones it started with.

How can I do this? So far, I've tried cy.json(), but that only returns the initial state of the graph.

Below is all of my cytoscape code.

```
class MyApp extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
    }
  
    render(){
      const elements = [ // Nodes and edges to be added initially
         { data: { id: 'one', label: 'Node 1' }, position: { x: 250, y: 250 } },
         { data: { id: 'two', label: 'Node 2' }, position: { x: 300, y: 250 } },
         { data: { source: 'one', target: 'two', label: 'Edge from Node1 to Node2' } }
      ];
  
      return <CytoscapeComponent 
      cy = {cy => { // Extensions and their options
        cy.contextMenus({
            menuItems: [
                {   // Adds the ability to add nodes from the right-click menu
                    id: 'add-node',
                    content: 'add node',
                    tooltipText: 'add node',
                    image: {src: "./node_modules/cytoscape-context-menus/assets/add.svg", width: 12, height: 12, x: 6, y: 4},
                    coreAsWell: true,
                    // When we move adding nodes to a sidebar, probably use this as reference
                    onClickFunction: function (event) {
                        var data = {
                        group: 'nodes'
                        };
            
                        var pos = event.position || event.cyPosition;
            
                        cy.add({
                        data: data,
                        position: {
                            x: pos.x,
                            y: pos.y
                        }
                        });
                    }
                }
            ]
        })
      }}
      elements={elements} 
      style={ { width: '100%', height: '40vmax'} } />;
    }
  }
```

Comment: `cy.json()` will return current state of the graph not the initial

Comment: It ended up working as you stated for whatever reason. But thank you